# Using Fraunhofer diffraction when projecting on a curved screen

Tags: optics, diffraction

Suppose I have a slit very far away from a curved screen (suppose part of a circle). If the screen was flat, the far field approximation is due to the Fraunhofer diffraction, and is given by
$$
U(x,y,z) = \frac{ik}{2\pi z}\cdot e^{ik\left(z + \frac{x^2+y^2}{2z}\right)}\cdot \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}U(x',y',0)\cdot e^{\frac{ikxx'}{z} + \frac{ikyy'}{z}}dx'dy'
$$
where $U(x,y,0)$ is the slit's function.

How do I calculate this when the screen is curved?

Comment: @JonTravi how is that the Fraunhofer diffraction integral? x and y don't even appear under the integral sign and $\frac{kx'}{z}$ is not unit free so how are you going to evaluate that exponential? Also that prefactor in front also looks suspicious, too.

Comment: @JonTravi, I think that your integral should be bound by the slit dimensions but it is up to you. The Fraunhofer integral formula still holds. Your question is essentially a matter of projecting what you would obtain with a flat screen onto a curved screen. It is more a geometrical problem than a diffraction one I would say. However, be aware that the formula you use of diffraction is only valid for small angles.

Comment: @numrok I am not sure what you do not like about this integral? How would you correct it ?

Comment: @RonanTarikDrevon did it get edited? I swear there was an x missing in the exponent a week ago and some other confusing stuff. if not i must have mistead something and i apologize.

Comment: @numrock I suspected it but was not sure. That's why I asked.